# How to restrict Copy, Paste for UITextField in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

i want to restrict the copy or Paste option for particular UITextfield in my Application.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following piece of code in the implementation file of the view controller which containing the `UITextField`

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    if (menuController) {
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

OR

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:) // or @selector(copy:)
        return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a subclass of UITextField.

In that subclass, implement

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (sel_isEqual(action, @selector(copy:))) //@selector(paste:) { 
        return NO;
    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Then use this subclass for the field that you don't want to be able to copy in, and use a regular UITextField for the one that you can copy from.

Refer this URL for more info:-

[iPhone – Disable the Cut/Copy/Paste Menu on UITextField](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/04/12/iphone-disable-the-cutcopypaste-menu-on-uitextfield/)

[UIResponder](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/canPerformAction%3awithSender%3a)

[iPhone SDK Development](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/21715-how-disable-cut-copy-paste-feature.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it like this:

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:)) {
        return NO;
    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Otherwise you can write:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
```

To make your UITextField non-editable.